# How to check continuity of $f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(ax + x^2)}{x}\, dx$ on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How can I see the continuity of $f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(ax + x^2)}{x}\, dx$  on $[0,1]$?
I have no idea how to approach.
Any comment would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a, b\in \Bbb R$. For fixed $x\in [0,1]$, the mean value theorem gives $$\sin(ax + x^2) - \sin(bx + x^2) = x\cos(cx + x^2)(a - b),$$ where $c$ is a number between $a$ and $b$. Thus $$|\sin(ax + x^2) - \sin(bx + x^2)| \le x|a - b|.$$ Since this holds for every $x\in [0,1]$,  we have $$|f(a) - f(b)| \le \int_0^1 |\sin(ax + x^2) - \sin(bx + x^2)|\frac{dx}{x} \le \int_0^1 |a - b|\, dx = |a - b|.$$ Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got another question. Let's say I see this problem for the first time, then from what information given, do I come up with mean value theorem? This was not the exact case but I have hard time initiate the think process. I guess I do not have enough intuition.

Comment: Hi @Kane, your function is of the form $f(a) = \int_0^1 F(a,x)\, dx$. A wishful thought is to have $|F(a,x) - F(b,x)| \le C|a - b|$ for some constant $C$, because then we would have $|f(a) - f(b)| \le C|a - b|$. Knowing that the sine has derivative bounded by $1$, it would be worth a shot to use MVT on $\sin(ax + x^2)$ (with respect to the parameter $a$) to get that relationship $|f(a) - f(b)| \le C|a - b|$, which works in this case (with $C = 1$).

Comment: I see. I really appreciate your comment.